# How to authenticate react-route in respect to axios response

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to render component if `isAuthenticated()` method returns true, everything works fine until I return true/false from axios response, It seems promises are ignored. How should I modify my code, should I be using diferent aproach?

this is my `isAuthenticate()`:

```
 isAuthenticated = () =>{
        const cookie = new Cookie();

        axios.get("/api/check", {
            headers : {
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + cookie.get('access_token')
            }})
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data.auth"); //returns actuall value
                return response.data.auth; // completely ignored
            })
            .catch(function (response) {
                console.log("Klaida isAuthenticated PrivateRoute");
                return false;
            });
    };
```

This is my `render()`

```
render() {
        const {component: Component, ...rest} = this.props;

        const renderRoute = props => {
            const to = {
                pathname: '/login',
                state: {from: props.location}
            };
            if (this.isAuthenticated) {
                return (
                    <Component {...props} />
                );
            } else {
                return (
                    <Redirect to={to}/>
                );
            }
        };

        return (
            <Route {...rest} render={renderRoute}/>
        );
    }
```

**EDIT** 
So I moved my logic from `isAuthenticated()` to `componentWillMount()` method and added state element to know when fetching is completed like so :

```
componentWillMount() {
        const cookie = new Cookie();
        let self =this;
        axios.get("/api/check", {
            headers : {
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + cookie.get('access_token')
            }})
            .then(function (response) {
                self.setState({
                    auth: response.data.auth,
                    res: true
                });
                console.log(self.state.auth)
            })
            .catch(function (response) {
                console.log("Klaida isAuthenticated PrivateRoute");
            });
    }
```

and I did conditional rendering when waiting for response:

```
if(this.state.res){
             return (
                 <Route {...rest} render={renderRoute}/>
             );
         }else{
             return (
                 'loading..'
             );
         }
```

And everything else is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 isAuthenticated = () =>{
        const cookie = new Cookie();

        axios.get("/api/check", {
            headers : {
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + cookie.get('access_token')
            }})
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data.auth"); //returns actuall value
                return response.data.auth; // <-- here you're returning this from your callback not from your isAuthenticated method
            })
            .catch(function (response) {
                console.log("Klaida isAuthenticated PrivateRoute");
                return false;
            });
}
```

and

```
if (this.isAuthenticated) // <-- here you're not even calling your method
```

The correct way to do this will be to have some state in your component and set your state depending on what your response is, and then render according to your state

Comment: You are right, I also had to do conditional rendering - when waiting for response, render loading screen.